# How to divide recorded jmeter recording and repeat only certain step

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, load-testing

I created simple test using JMeter recorder:

1. login to application
2. display dashboard

Is it possible to divide test into two steps (logining and displaying dashboard) and when number of user is increased (because of rump up setting) repeat only the second step?

After user loging to application only dashboard should be refreshed/displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform "login to application" only once you can put it under a [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)

If you want to stop doing "login to application" when the number of active users is more than some defined value - put it under [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) and use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

```
${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumberOfThreads() < 42,)}
```

replace `42` with target users threshold when you want to stop executing the
"login to application" request